# Android ListView Select Animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, listview-adapter

How can I set up the animation when the user selects an element in a listview?

I am making my own listview adapter to set even rows with a pink background and odd rows with a purple background. The only problem is that I am not sure how to set the animation for the user clicking ("touching") an element.

I thought of implementing OnTouchListener and changing the background to green when selected BUT I have buttons inside the rows that might no longer work due to OnTouchListener being implemented. Is this true?

Code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // position is the element's id to use
        // convertView is either null -> create a new view for this element!
        //                or not null -> re-use this given view for element!
        // parent is the listview all the elements are in    

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

            // here you must do whatever is needed to populate the elements of your
            // list element layout
            ...
        } else {
            // re-use the given convert view

            // here you must set all the elements to the required values
        }

        // your drawable here for this element 
        convertView.setBackground(...);

        // maybe here's more to do with the view
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a StateListDrawable with a defined item for state_selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
    ...Other States...
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

This way, when the list item is selected it will use that "selected" graphic automatically.